# Some prompt() comment exercises

Tags: javascript

I'm very beginner level at javascript and I would like to find solutions to these exercises:
1.  Write a script that prompts the visitor for two numbers [use JavaScript build-in function `prompt()`]. Then, displays the two numbers and their sum as follows:

```
You entered: 5 and 2
Sum:  7
```

2. Write a script that prompts the visitor for two numbers, then displays the two numbers and their sum, difference, product, quotient, and modulus in the document. For instance, if the visitor entered `5` and `2`, the results would display as follows:

```
You entered:  5 and 2
Sum: 7
Difference: 3
Product: 10
Quotient: 2.5
Modulus: 1
```

3. Write a script that prompts the visitor for three numbers, then calculates and displays their average.
4. Write a script that prompts the visitor for the number of hours he or she worked that week. Don’t forget that hours over `40` are paid at time and a half. Here’s what the display should look like if the visitor entered  `35 hours` at `$10/hour`:

```
Total Hours Worked:   35
Regular Pay:  35  hours @ $10/hour =  $350
Overtime Pay:  0 hours  @ $15/hour = $0
Total Pay:  $350
```

Comment: Please don't post your homework here. I don't mind answering the most rudimentary questions because I was once a beginner myself too. I'm happy to help another coder to grow, but if you don't want to do work it's a different story altogether.

Comment: This sounds like homework....At least include a fiddle to show us what you've already done.

Comment: @Schien I was just about to call the OP out on that same thing. We like code examples first. ~Edit: As in, show us what you've tried so far, and anything that may have shown up in your console.

Comment: I Know, been trying and didn't get any good results

Comment: but yes let me show you my work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
(function(show, askFor){
  var first = +askFor("The first number:"),
    +second = askFor("The second number:");
  show([
    "You entered:", first, "and", second, 
    "Sum:", first+second
  ].join(" "));
})(alert, prompt);

(function(show, askFor){
  var first = +askFor("The first number:"),
    second = +askFor("The second number:");
  show([
    "You entered:", first, "and", second,
    "Sum:", first + second,
    "Difference:", first - second,
    "Product:", first * second,
    "Quotient:", first / second,
    "Modulus:", first % second
  ].join(" "));
})(alert, prompt);

(function(show, askFor){
  var first = +askFor("The first number:"),
    second = +askFor("The second number:"),
    third = +askFor("The third number:");
  show("The average of those numbers: "+ (first+second+third)/3);
})(alert, prompt);

(function(show, askFor){
  var hours = +askFor("How much you worked this week:"),
    rate = +askFor("And what's your hourly rate:"),
    overtimeRate = rate*1.5,
    regularHours = Math.min(40, hours),
    overtimeHours = Math.max(0, hours-40),
    regularPay = rate*regularHours,
    overtimePay = overtimeRate*overtimeHours;
  show([
    "Total Hours Worked:", hours,
    " Regular Pay:", regularHours, 
    " hours @ $", rate, "/hour", 
    " = $", regularPay, 
    " Overtime Pay:", overtimeHours,
    " hours @ $", overtimeRate, "/hour",
    " = $", overtimePay, 
    " Total Pay: $", regularPay+overtimePay  
  ].join(""));
})(alert, prompt);
```

Comment: lol...He is a beginner not an expert.

Comment: Meh, I like this because then show and askFor can be DOM manipulating functions that use different I/O, and it's also clear what's going on inside the functions :P

Comment: thanls, I appreciate the help

Comment: for the first one I got this but I know that it might be wrong

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function MathThing()
{
   firstnumber = prompt("Give me a number.", "");
   secondnumber = prompt("Give me another number.", "");
   total = firstnumber + secondnumber;

   alert(firstnumber + " + " + secondnumber + " = " + total);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="javascript:MathThing()">Click me</a>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

you may use javascript prompt method to take the user input an save this value in variable:

```
var num1 = prompt("Enter first number");
```

same code you can use for getting num2,num3 from the user than make your computation and get the result.

Note: **practice is the best thing to learn javascript or I must say anything. so keep practicing and whenever you face any problem show us. we all are here to help each other.**